# Converting flv file into swf using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been trying to convert a flv file into swf file. How can I convert the flv video into swf file using C#?

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking for the algorithm for how to do the conversion in C# then that is far outside the scope of a simple SO-question.

But instead of doing that I would recommend you use one of many existing command-line tools for doing the conversion. The tools can be called from your C# code using the [Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx). When the conversion tool finishes you can read out the converted file and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: FFmpeg would do the Job ,using you're solution